# NoSuchElementException on performing Mousehover action in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a webpage in which I am trying to perform a mouse hover.. There is an element named "Entity Records" on which if you hover your mouse it displays a menu. In that menu I need to click on an element named Create New record.

I have tried 3 different set of codes but it's not working for me..

1st One:

```
 WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("\\...."));
    action.moveToElement(el).build().perform();
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("..."))).click().build().perform();
```

2nd one:

```
WebElement entityrecordsmenu = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("..."));
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.moveToElement(entityrecordsmenu).build().perform();
    WebElement createnewrecord = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("..."));
    createnewrecord.click();
```

3rd one:

```
Actions action2 = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("...));
    action2.moveToElement(ele).build().perform();
    Actions build2 = new Actions(driver);
    build2.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("..."))).click().build().perform();
```

1st and 2nd code are doing the mouse hover fine, but its not clicking on the menu element. Can anyone suggest me the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

After mouse hover, try by giving some wait to get that element displayed and then click.

```
 WebElement entityrecordsmenu = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("..."));
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.moveToElement(entityrecordsmenu).build().perform();
    //provide wait here to display dropdown
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //some time implicity wait may fails then use thread.sleep
    //Thread.sleep(3000);
    WebElement createnewrecord = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("..."));
    createnewrecord.click();

    //if still above once does  not work you can try
    Actions builder1 = new Actions(driver);
    builder1.moveToElement(entityrecordsmenu).click(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("..."))).build().perform();
```

Thank You,
Murali